# Java reading nth line

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read a specific line from a text file, however I don't want to load the file into memory (it can get really big).

I have been looking but every example i have found requires either to read every line (this would slow my code down as there are over 100,000 lines) or load the whole thing into an array and get the correct element (file will have alot of lines to input).

An example of what I want to do:

```
String line = File.getLine(5);
```

"code is not actual code, it is made up to show the principle of what i want"

Is there a way to do this?

-----Edit-----

I have just realized this file will be written too in between reading lines (adding to the end of the file).

Comment: Reading through every line of a 100000 line file is an extremely quick operation, why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: How about something like [skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#skip(long))? But yeah, you need a fixed line length or the line start position for each line, or at least an idea of the line length and a unique ID per line (in which case you may need a [Random Access File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) if you overshoot).

Comment: Try with seek(long pos) method in RandomAccessFile and then use readLine() to get the data.

Comment: What is your access pattern?  Do you read the nth line and not really use the file again, do you read the lines more or less sequentially (always incrementing n and never decrementing it), or do you read many random lines within this file?

Comment: there is 2 functions i am after, 1) read a line which the user selects, 2) read new lines added since the last read. i plan to read the file every 10 seconds. i have got the line count and can find out the new line numbers but i need to read that line

Comment: @NoLiver92 it sounds to me like you need map from line numbers to offsets to address use-case 1, and you just need to save the most recent offset (instead of the most recent line number) to address use-case 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16206497/44737

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Not unless the lines are of a fixed number of bytes each, no.

You don't have to actually *keep* each line in memory - but you've got to read through the whole file to get to the line you want, as otherwise you won't know where to start reading.

Comment: oh ok i guess ill have to read it line by line unless if what rob said below works. its still reading it by line by line but you map which line is what offset so you can move the pointer to where you want

Answer (score 4):

You *have to* read the file line by line. Otherwise how do you know when you have gotten to line 5 (as in your example)?

Edit:

You might also want to check out [Random Access Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) which could be helpful if you know how many bytes per line, as Jon Skeet has said.

Comment: Exactly, and even with Random Access files you don't have the ability to read by line--just by byte. It's important to remember that lines (in a file on a file system) are arbitrarily denoted by newline characters. A 1KB file could have 1024 lines in it, or just one

Comment: @darkpbj RandomAccessFile has a readLine() method, so I think you mean to say that RandomAccessFile doesn't have the ability to _seek_ by line.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a BufferedReader (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), because you can specify your buffer size. You could do something like:

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"), 1024);

```
in.readLine();
in.readLine();
in.readLine();
in.readLine();
String line = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1) read a line which the user selects,

If you only need to read a user-selected line once or infrequently (or if the file is small enough), then you just have to read the file line-by-line from the start, until you get to the selected line.

If, on the other hand you need to read a user-selected line frequently, you should build an index of line numbers and offsets.  So, for example, line 42 corresponds to an offset of 2347 bytes into the file.  Ideally, then, you would only read the entire file once and store the index--for example, in a map, using the line numbers as keys and offsets as values.

> 2) read new lines added since
>   the last read. i plan to read the file every 10 seconds. i have got
>   the line count and can find out the new line numbers but i need to
>   read that line

For the second point, you can simply save the current offset into the file instead of saving the current line number--but it certainly wouldn't hurt to continue building the index if it will continue to provide a significant performance benefit.

1. Use RandomAccessFile.seek(long offset) to set the file pointer to the most recently saved offset (confirm the file is longer than the most recently saved offset first--if not, nothing new has been appended).
2. Use RandomAccessFile.readLine() to read a line of the file
3. Call RandomAccessFile.getFilePointer() to get the current offset after reading the line and optionally put(currLineNo+1, offset) into the index.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until reaching the end of the file.

But don't get too carried away with performance optimizations unless the performance is already a problem or is highly likely to be a problem.

Comment: This looks good, i will try it when i get home tonight (had to go into work today) Thanks

Comment: Someone has a snippet of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

For small files:

```
String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).get(n);
```

For large files:

```
String line;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    line = lines.skip(n).findFirst().get();
}
```

Java 7:

```
String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        br.readLine();
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Source: [Reading nth line from file](https://programming.guide/java/reading-nth-line-from-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to build an index of where each line is (you only need to record the end of each line)  Without a way to randomly access a line based on an index from the start, you have to read every byte before that line.

BTW: Reading 100,000 lines might take only one second on a fast machine.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a big concern here and you are frequently reading random lines from a static file then you can optimize this a bit by reading through the file and building an index (basically just a `long[]`) of the starting offset of each line of the file.

Once you have this you know exactly where to jump to in the file and then you can read up to the next newline character to retrieve the full line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of some code I had which will read a file and write every 10th line including the first line to a new file (writer.) You can always replace the try section with whatever you want to do.  To change the number of lines to read just change the 0 in the if statement "lc.endsWith("0")" to whatever line you want to read.  But if the file is being written to as you read it, this code will only work with the data that is contained inside the file when you run this code.

```
            LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int linecount=lnr.getLineNumber();
            lnr.close();

        for (int i=0; i<=linecount; i++){

            //read lines
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String lc = String.valueOf(i);

            if (lc.endsWith("0")){

                try{

                    writer.append(line+"\n");
                    writer.flush();

                    }catch(Exception ee){
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. This reads every line
2. `lc.endsWith("0")` is replaceable with `((i % 10) == 0)`