# How to move between rows in the file?

Tags: java

If I have the file and there are 30 rows.How can I start reading from the 14th row?How to realize that in Java?are there any classes or methods in Java to move file pointer between rows?

Comment: Unless you know the exact byte index at which to start reading (this could be the case if your records have a fixed length), it's probably easiest to read line by line and skip the first 13. If you *do* know the byte index, you can use a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: This question demonstrates zero research effort. What have you already tried?  (If you won't try yourself, why do you expect others to try for you?)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53703424/2993413) answer your question?

Comment: So how to skip first 13 rows?

Comment: Completely explained in the linked answer above your last comment.

Comment: Did SO change the criteria for upvotes ?

Comment: Is the file binary or a CSV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on my eclipse and it worked for me.

package Codechef;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class readLineFromFile {


     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("E:\\text.txt")).get(7);
            System.out.println(line);  
        }

}
```

***output:***

```
h
```

- my text.txt file

  a 
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  g
  h
  i
  k

this might help you

Comment: In which way does this address the question or read the specified column ?